# How to determine two unknown voltage sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I have this question from my electrical circuits class that i can't get my head around at all. Any help would be appreciated.

On the left there is a voltage source of unknown polarity and voltage (marked by a ?). On the right the voltage source's polarity is known but the voltage itself is not (it is a 9v battery but we were told to ignore this as it is not the exact output voltage). I have also labelled the positive and negative terminals of the ammeters A1 and A2 with their readings above.

This is the part of the question that i'm stuck on:

[image: Question]

I have the voltages of each resistor (5.0243V for the 470ohm, 14.212V for the 2.2kohm and 4.23V for the 1kohm). I know that per KVL that the sum of all the voltages in the circuit should be 0, however i'm not sure how to add in the voltage of the 1kohm resistor to this equation or how to attribute these voltages to each source.
[image: Circuit Diagram]

Apologies in advance if I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: You're missing the equations from Kirchhoff's laws. It's okay if you can't solve it completely but you have to show what you've done so far. We're not a homework service.

Comment: Set up what you do know and it will start making sense.  In two areas you have amps and Resistance. V = Amps x ohms.

Comment: @Null I have added in what i already know to the post now. Apologies this wasn't included in the first place

Comment: _"Based on your knowledge of Kirchhoff's laws..."_ - perhaps some revision is needed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law

Comment: Hint: the current through `1kOhm` is `17.15mA`, so you know that the voltage accross it is `17.15V`

Comment: @SimSon, I think you made a sign error in your calculation.

Comment: The sum of the voltages around a loop = 0.  Any loop.  That's what KVL essentially means.

Comment: You should **try** writing some equations according to Kirchhoff's laws. Show us what you think might be the right approach. Tell us specifically what is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner, you should always redraw the circuit *completely annotated*, to avoid any ambiguity:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUT9yh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've removed the ammeters because they are a distraction, and (assuming they are ideal) make no difference to the circuit's behaviour. I've also placed current arrows everywhere and voltage polarities across every element.

There are a couple of points where you need to take great care:

1. For resistors you *must* indictate voltage polarity and current direction in a manner that conforms to reality. That is, in a resistor, current always flows from higher potential to lower. If you have a resistor in your circuit where your current arrow points from low potential to high, you'll have trouble. If you have no idea what the current direction or voltage polarity for some resistor is, just make sure that your annotated polarity and current is consistent with this rule. True polarity will emerge in the analysis.
   For example, in my drawing I have no idea about the direction of I3, or the polarity of voltage across R3, so I guessed, but importantly my guess is consistent with the requirement that current flow from high potential (+) to low (–).
2. For voltage and current sources, you may not know the polarity beforehand. However, annotate them with arbitrarily chosen positive or negative signs, and the actual polarity will be revealed in the analysis.
   This is what I have done for voltage source Va here, which I know nothing about. I have guessed its polarity, and that's OK, because if guessed wrong I'll just get a negative value for Va.

For KVL, remember that as you travel around a loop, each time you traverse an element, you may go up in potential, in which case you add, or your may go down in potential, in which case you subtract. To know whether to add or subtract, refer to your annotated polarity symbols. For example, travelling counter-clockwise from node X, I experience a drop in potential as I traverse R1 (so I subtract), another drop as I cross over Va, but a rise in potential across R3 (so I add). Since I must end up with the same potential at X as when I left it, these operations all total zero.

For KCL, use the the arrow directions to tell you whether you should be adding or subtracting. Personally, I prefer the convention that currents entering a node (such as the 10.69mA entering node X) are to be added, and currents leaving (such as I3) are to be subtracted.

I think now you have all the information you need to obtain all the simultaneous equations by applying KCL, KVL and Ohm's law to this circuit, and solve them.

Lastly, when you get a negative value for any current or voltage, that simply means you guessed the polarity wrong. That's fine, the result is still valid. You can, if you choose, reverse the arrow or polarity symbols, and change the negative value to positive. That might make it more intuitive/easy to read on the schematic.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer, this really helped me understand KVL itself and not just this specific question.